# Load external resource before extending jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following script (Also at http://jsbin.com/yegike/1/).  If I try to create variable `map` before including the google maps link, I get a `ReferenceError: google is not defined` error.  Without moving the link before the script, is it possible to eliminate this error?  Even if the answer is "no", I would appreciate an explanation on what is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style type="text/css">
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script> -->
        <script>
            (function($){
                var map = new google.maps.LatLng(47.64864, -122.348927);
                }(jQuery));
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call a method named maps within the google namespace which is defined in your commented out script. The solution for this is to use the jQuery.ready method to execute your code when the page has been loaded (including your script include at the bottom of the page). Wrap your function within this and you should be good to go:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var map = new google.maps.LatLng(47.64864, -122.348927);
});
```

For more information about ready you can check out the always useful jQuery API:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks floatingeye.  I thought the purpose of `$( document ).ready(function() {...});` DOM is loaded.  No?  While it seems to work, I wouldn't have expected to do so.

Comment: You're exactly correct, but the <script> element is actually a dom element. So it will load everything including scripts then execute your code. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this which waits until the page is loaded and if it takes google a while to load, then it will try again:

```
var map;
function makeMap() {
  if (google && google.maps) { // google loaded?
    map = new google.maps.LatLng(47.64864, -122.348927);
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(makeMap,200); // try again
}
$(function(){ // on page load instead of Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)
   makeMap();         
});
```